# Function table C syntax

Tags: c

I was reading the Java JNI docs. In [example 4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp2556) they show a function table as it is supposedly outlined in the C code. Here's a glimpse:

```
const struct JNINativeInterface ... = {

NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
GetVersion,
 . . .
};
```

The spaced elipse inside the struct is mine, but the regular one appearing after the structname 'JNINativeInterface' is theirs.

I've never set about to write a function table in C. Is the elipse after the structname hiding something or is that special C syntax that I don't know?

Comment: The `...` is supposed to be the name of the structure variable. It can be anything you feel, which is probably why they left out an explicit name.

Comment: Probably, you can set valid function pointer at each NULL.

Comment: Simply replace `...` with the name you want to give the table, e.g. `jniFunctionTable`

Comment: oh ok that totally threw me. Leaving that out for the JNI implementers is catering to a pretty small crowd!

Comment: Please note, that for readability purposes, one should use the struct member names in the initializer: `struct Foo myFoo = { .bar = myBar, .baz = myBaz, ... };` That way you can easily see what value is assigned to which member, and the correctness of the initialization is not dependent on the *order* in which the struct members are defined. For example with this definition `struct Foo { int bar, baz; };` the initialization `struct Foo myFoo = { myBaz, myBar };` would be an error, but the initialization `struct Foo myFoo = { .baz = myBaz, .bar = myBar };` does the expected thing.